# Trying to disable add to cart button on the weekends in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been working on a website that will be selling products during the week, but won't be accepting orders throughout the weekend. I've been using the following code through the plugin Snippets on WordPress, but it seems to not be taking effect. Thanks for the help

```
function is_shop_open() {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Port_of_Spain');
    $days_opened = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // mondays, tuesdays, wednesdays, thursdays and fridays
    if(in_array( date(w), $days_opened, true )){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    
}

function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    add_action( 'wp', 'cross_remove_add_to_cart_product_categories' );

}

function cross_remove_add_to_cart_product_categories(){
    if( is_product_category( 'Regular Menu Items' ) && is_shop_open() == false) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I'm using the plugin WPC Product Timer for WooCommerce for further day/time restrictions. Not sure if this may be relevant to the issue stated above

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
function is_shop_open()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Port_of_Spain');
    $days_opened = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // mondays, tuesdays, wednesdays, thursdays and fridays
    if (in_array(date(w), $days_opened, true)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    
}

add_action('init', 'cross_remove_add_to_cart_product_categories');

function cross_remove_add_to_cart_product_categories()
{
    if (is_product_category('Regular Menu Items') && !is_shop_open()) {
        
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
        
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!. Sadly, there was no change. I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with the sequence the code is being executed in. Maybe the WPC Product Timer Plugin is overriding the code?